# unattended-upgrades needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: 16.04, unattended-upgrades

I have been facing this problem on ubuntu 16.04. I tried to fix by uncommenting  `"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";` this line in  `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, but no luck. Even, if I  run `sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades` throwing the same error.

I request your solutions to fix this problem.

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved the problem!!